# What is the text message platform used by Magic startup

Tags: sms, startup

Magic is a startup in California with a simple concept : you ask them whatever you want by text message, like shopping food and beers or meeting a celebrity.

I'm interested in their text message platform, anyone have information ?

https://getmagicnow.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like they use Twilio. From their blog:
https://www.getmagicnow.com/engineering/hn7

Twilio:
https://www.twilio.com/

Twilio's SMS product: 
https://www.twilio.com/sms